# Parsing a text-file table and aggregating information

Tags: sed, awk, perl

I have long text file with the following columns, space-delimited:

```
Id            Pos Ref  Var  Cn   SF:R1   SR  He  Ho NC       
cm|371443199  22  G     A    R   Pass:8   0   1  0  0       
cm|371443199  25  C     A    M   Pass:13  0   0  1  0
cm|371443199  22  G     A    R   Pass:8   0   1  0  0        
cm|367079424  17  C     G    S   Pass:19  0   0  1  0      
cm|371443198  17  G     A    R   Pass:18  0   1  0  0       
cm|367079424  17  G     A    R   Pass:18  0   0  1  0
```

I want to generate a table that lists each unique ID along with counts for:

- How many times that ID occurred
- How many of those rows were passing (column 6)
- How many had an `He` value (column 8)
- How many had an `Ho` value (column 9)

In this case:

```
Id            CountId  Countpass   CountHe CountHO
cm|371443199   3        3          2        1
cm|367079424   2        2          0        2
```

How can I go about generating that table?

Comment: What happened to row #5?

Comment: sorry, row#5 also occurs, i have just shown two examples in output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution in `awk` which uses 4 arrays to count the 4 pieces of information you need. The output from `awk` is then fed into `column` which aligns the columns up nicely. (Note that this could also have been done in `awk` using `printf`.)

```
awk 'NR>1 {
    id[$1]++
    if($6 ~ /Pass/) pass[$1]++
    if($8 ~ /1/) he[$1]++
    if($9 ~ /1/) ho[$1]++
} 
END {
   print "Id CountId Countpass CountHe CountHO"
   for(i in id)
      print i" "id[i]" "(pass[i]?pass[i]:0)" "(he[i]?he[i]:0)" "(ho[i]?ho[i]:0)
}' input.txt | column -t
```

**Output:**

```
Id            CountId  Countpass  CountHe  CountHO
cm|371443198  1        1          1        0
cm|371443199  3        3          2        1
cm|367079424  2        2          0        2
```

Comment: To get the output sequence as FIFO-ish (as mentioned in a comment to *Birei's* answer, only minor changes are needed ... **(1)** Add a new line after the opening `{` brace: `if(!id[$1]) nr[ln++]=$1` ...  **(2)** Remove the line `for(i in id)` and replace it with: `for( n=0;n<ln;n++ ) { i=nr[n]` ... **(3)** Change the closing `}` brace to  `}}` to balance the extra brace introduced in (2) -- (+1 btw)

Answer (score 4):

One way using `perl` assuming `infile` has content of your question (IDs won't be necessarily in same order in output because I use a hash to save them):

Content of `script.pl`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my (%data);

while ( <> ) { 

    ## Omit header.
    next if $. == 1;

    ## Remove last '\n'.
    chomp;

    ## Split line in spaces.
    my @f = split;

    ## If this ID exists, get previously values and add values of this
    ## line to them. Otherwise, begin to count now.
    my @counts = exists $data{ $f[0] } ? @{ $data{ $f[0] } } : (); 
    $counts[0]++;
    $counts[1]++ if substr( $f[5], 0, 4 ) eq q|Pass|;
    $counts[2] += $f[7];
    $counts[3] += $f[8];
    splice @{ $data{ $f[0] } }, 0, @{ $data{ $f[0] } }, @counts; 
}

## Format output.
my $print_format = qq|%-15s %-10s %-12s %-10s %-10s\n|;

## Print header.
printf $print_format, qw|Id CountId CountPass CountHe CountHo|;

## For every ID saved in the hash print acumulated values.
for my $id ( keys %data ) { 
    printf $print_format, $id, @{ $data{ $id } };
}
```

Run it like:

```
perl script.pl infile
```

With following output:

```
Id              CountId    CountPass    CountHe    CountHo   
cm|371443198    1          1            1          0         
cm|371443199    3          3            2          1         
cm|367079424    2          2            0          2
```

Comment: thanks. I get error Use of uninitialized value in printf at script.pl line 35. Is it possible to display ID's in the same order as appear in the input file